# iOS 8 UICollectionViewLayout Switching Mysterious Crash in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am new working with `UICollectionView`. I am trying to switch `UICollectionViewLayout` from grid to list and vice versa using the below code:

```
@IBAction func switchLayout(sender: AnyObject) {
    isGridLayout = !isGridLayout

    collectionView?.reloadData()

    if isGridLayout {            

        collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in
            self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
            self.collectionView?.setCollectionViewLayout(self.gridLayout, animated: true)
            }, completion: { (completion) -> Void in
        })

    } else {            

        collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in
            self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
            self.collectionView?.setCollectionViewLayout(self.listLayout, animated: true)
            }, completion: { (completion) -> Void in
        })            
    }
}
```

I consistently get the below crash on `setCollectionViewLayout:animated:` method, which I don't understand. Any help on fixing this crash would be great!

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0})'
```

The project is available in [github](https://github.com/dhanushram/collectionViewSampleCrash). Its a modified form of this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1).

Comment: Any luck to fix this issue? Facing same

Comment: @DineshHudinwal, have you figured out the problem? what's the solution?

Comment: @jacky nope! Rather i altered the application flow

Comment: @jacky used two different controllers one for grid other for list

Answer (score 2):

Because you set the `headerReferenceSize` in your FlowLayout. It means that the collectionView will have a Supplementary View.

So comment out the code of `headerReferenceSize` or implement the `collectionView(_:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:at:)` in your ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and at the end I was missing to implement layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath() in UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes subclass.

This is my implementation

```
override func prepareLayout() {
    super.prepareLayout()

    if let numberOfItems = self.collectionView?.numberOfItemsInSection(0) {
        var left: CGFloat = self.sectionInset.left
        let centerY = CGRectGetMidY((self.collectionView?.bounds)!)
        for item in 0..<numberOfItems {
            let itemFrame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: left, y: centerY - (self.itemSize.height / 2)), size: self.itemSize)
            let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWithIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forItem: item, inSection: 0))
            attributes.size = ITEM_SIZE
            attributes.frame = itemFrame
            attributes.alpha = 1
            attributes.zIndex = 1
            attributes.hidden = false

            self.layoutAttributes.append(attributes)

            left += self.itemSize.width + self.minimumInteritemSpacing
        }

        let contentWidth: CGFloat = self.sectionInset.left + (CGFloat(numberOfItems) * (self.itemSize.width + self.minimumInteritemSpacing) - self.minimumInteritemSpacing) + self.sectionInset.right
        self.contentSize = CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: (self.collectionView?.bounds.height)!)
    }
}

override func layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    return self.layoutAttributes[indexPath.item]
}

override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    var validAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
    for attributes in self.layoutAttributes {
        if CGRectIntersectsRect(attributes.frame, rect) {
            validAttributes.append(attributes)
        }
    }

    return validAttributes
}

override func collectionViewContentSize() -> CGSize {
    return self.contentSize
}
```